# How to combine multiple custom management commands in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-manage.py, django-commands, django-4.1

I wrote a set of commands for my Django project in the usual way. Is it possible to combine multiple commands into one command?

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    """ import all files in media in dir and add to db
    after call  process to generate thumbnails  """

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
       ...
```

To make easy steps I have commands like: import files, read metadata from files, create thumbnails etc. The goal now is to create a "do all" command that somehow imports these commands and executes them one after another.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a DoAll command and use django `django.core.management.call_command` to run all your subcommands. Try something like below:

```
class FoobarCommand(BaseCommand):
    """ call foo and bar commands """

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        call_command("foo_command", *args, **options)
        call_command("bar_command", *args, **options)
```